# Post Request Issue with Postman

Tags: java, post, postman

Can someone please help me on how to send a POST request with the following parameters:

```
  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response restAPIforLocation(@QueryParam("location") String location, String Params)
```

I tried sending one with the following arguments inside Body in Postman:

```
{
 "location": "new york",
 "Params": "{}"
}
```

However on sending the above request I am getting the location string as null.

Comment: @QueryParam has to parse query parameters in URL I think. And you are providing this information in request body.

Comment: I thought you only passed params in URL for GET requests.

Comment: You can do it for each HTTP method and this practice is OK. Try to create a wrapper  class for your body with location and Params field and pass it to controller without any annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a request with POSTMAN for a provided controller method:
`your-url?location=some_location`
location is a query parameter so pass in URL after *?* symlol.
To send `Params` just send a empty JSON body (simply use brackets `{ }`)

```
POST  HTTP/1.1
Host: url?location=your_location
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3cf60381-a9f1-1610-53e0-91be19a68266

{

}
```

It is a raw representation of the request in POSTMAN

Answer (score 0):

Use use annotation `@QueryParam('location')` which causes that the value is expected as Query Parameter.

In your example you send the info in the payload (body) of the request.
To receive this value in your function correctly you need to use the annotation `@FormParam('location')`.

More Details:

> Query Parameter
>
> Query parameter are special parameters that allow you to change the scope of the request to reflect a subset of resources. Put simply – you may want to retrieve data on a large
> number of resources, but wish to filter out some of the resources if they don’t
> match a name, type, size, state, or so forth.

.

> Body Parameter
>
> Body Parameters indicates when you need to construct a body of data for the endpoint to inspect. This is sometimes referred to as a payload. You build a body in whatever format is desired by the API. In Rubrik’s case, the format should be JSON, but other APIs might use XML, YAML, or something else entirely. Most all endpoints that need a body parameter are looking to change the resource’s data.

http://wahlnetwork.com/2017/09/25/working-with-restful-api-query-body-and-path-parameters/

Comment: You're right but i don't know the use case why he did it in this way. So I just tried to resolve his problem. What is better for which use case is maybe a question for software engineering community